# Http Utility 'doesn't exist in current context (API help)

Tags: c#

I'm trying to work with the coinmarketcap api and have been following their guide on how to call results into c#. I have been having a problem where it does not let me call results due to httputility not existing in the current context.

```cs
class CSharpExample
{
    private static string API_KEY = "c3c5ee7f-209b-4eb7-8db9-307c15f609d0";

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(makeAPICall());
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }

    static string makeAPICall()
    {
        var URL = new UriBuilder("https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest");

        var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
        queryString["start"] = "1";
        queryString["limit"] = "5000";
        queryString["convert"] = "GBP";

        URL.Query = queryString.ToString();

        var client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers.Add("c3c5ee7f-209b-4eb7-8db9-307c15f609d0", API_KEY);
        client.Headers.Add("Accepts", "application/json");
        return client.DownloadString(URL.ToString());

    }
}
```

Comment: That's not your real API key, is it?

Comment: Also, what error do you actually get, and on what line?

Comment: Are you `using System.Web;` ?

Comment: @stuartd dw its just a test api key given by the website. Apologies for my lack of clarity the error is located on line 25 on relation to httputility simply saying the name doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: @David System.Web is in use but it is saying for some reason that using the directive is uneccessary.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like `System.Web` isn't referenced in the project.  This looks like a Console Application, so it wouldn't be there by default.

In the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio, right-click on the "References" node in the project and select "Add Reference".  Navigate to the "Assemblies" to find and select `System.Web`.  Click "OK".

Once added as a reference for the project, ensure this directive is at the top of the file:

```
using System.Web;
```